# Constant Bit Signal in VHDL

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I need to declare a bit with the constant value of 1.

What almost worked was:

```
signal name: bit := '1';
```

but the value of "name" is always '0' in this case.

How can I do this properly?

Full code:

```
ENTITY sleA IS
PORT(
    signal sel: std_logic; 
    A: in bit_vector (3 downto 0);
    S: out bit_vector (3 downto 0)
);
end sleA;
architecture arq_sleA of sleA is
begin
    sel <= '1';
    S(3) <= ((not sel) and A(3)) or (sel and A(2));
    S(2) <= ((not sel) and A(2)) or (sel and A(1));
    S(1) <= ((not sel) and A(1)) or (sel and A(0));
    S(0) <= ((not sel) and A(0)) or (sel and sel);
end arq_sleA;
```

Comment: `constant name : bit := '1';`

Comment: I get the following error: Error (10597): VHDL Interface List error at slA.vhd(6): identifier "sel" must be a signal

Comment: Who is `sel`? A signal based solution: `signal mySignal : std_logic;` mySignal <= '1';

Comment: sel is the name i'm giving to the signal. With this method now i'm getting: Error (10568): VHDL error at slA.vhd(13): can't write to interface object "sel" of mode IN

Comment: please post more code, your error is nothing to do with the line in your question.

Comment: If it's an input port you don't want to set its value locally : set its value externally when you instantiate the entity. And you apparently want a signal so why did you say you wanted a constant?

Comment: I added the full code. I've tried several ways, as bit, signal, constant, none of them worked. And Brian, i just need it to always be 1, didn't know how to call it.

Answer (score 1):

If `sel` is an input for the entity then you can set the initial value in the entity's port:

```
port(
  sel: in std_logic := '1';
  A: in bit_vector (3 downto 0);
  S: out bit_vector (3 downto 0)
);
```

This will work in simulation, but for synthesis make sure your target technology supports initial "power-on" values (true for FPGAs, not so for ASICs). See [Is initialization necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897143/is-initialization-necessary)

Also note that `signal` is only used in the architecture body, not entity declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this entity always with a fixed value for `sel`, then remove the input port `sel` and declare a constant `sel` inside the architecture instead.

```
entity sleA is
port(
    A: in bit_vector (3 downto 0);
    S: out bit_vector (3 downto 0)
);
end sleA;
architecture arq_sleA of sleA is
    constant sel : std_logic := '1';
begin
    S(3) <= ((not sel) and A(3)) or (sel and A(2));
    S(2) <= ((not sel) and A(2)) or (sel and A(1));
    S(1) <= ((not sel) and A(1)) or (sel and A(0));
    S(0) <= ((not sel) and A(0)) or (sel and sel);
end arq_sleA;
```

If you want to use this entity several times with a different value for `sel`, then the input port must be kept (remove `signal` keyword). But, if you want to synthesize this unit also as a top-module with a fixed value for `sel`, instantiate it in a wrapper:

```
entity sleA_wrapper is
port(
    A: in bit_vector (3 downto 0);
    S: out bit_vector (3 downto 0)
);
end sleA_wrapper;
architecture rtl of sleA_wrapper is
    inst : entity work.sleA port map(sel => '1', A => A, S => S);
end rtl;
```

Now set this wrapper as the top-module for simulation and synthesis.